# firebaseでfunctions,hostingしているLINEBOTのHTTPClient.wrapErrorについて。

Tags: firebase, line

現在業務にて、firebase上でfunction,hostingしてLINEmessagingAPIを構築しようとしているのですが、webhookのコールバックが400エラーとなってしまいます。でも、なぜかテキストメッセージリプライだけは返してくれます。
しかしflexMessageのリプライとなりますと、どうしてもエラーで帰ってきません。
fireaseFunctionsのエラーコードは以下の通りです。

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at HTTPClient.wrapError (/srv/node_modules/@line/bot-sdk/dist/http.js:83:20)
    at HTTPClient.instance.interceptors.response.use.err (/srv/node_modules/@line/bot-sdk/dist/http.js:19:88)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

ちなみに、下のサイトを参考に、@line/bot-sdk/http.jsを修正してみましたが、ダメでした。
どなたかご教示いただけると助かります。

[linebot 動かせためも - Qiita](https://qiita.com/jesuissuyaa/items/575ed39d2430f51e21cf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決策という訳ではないのですが、LINE DevelopersのWebhook設定の「検証ボタン」からだと自分も同じエラーが表示されますが、普通にLINEの方からメッセージを投げると問題なく動きました。
LINE DevelopersのWebhook設定の「検証ボタン」から投げられている中身などを一度確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: おっしゃる内容と同じ状態です。FirebaseFunctionのログはエラー吐いてますが（その前に、res.sendStatus(200);することで、Webhook設定の検証ボタンも形式上クリアしました）なんか微妙ですね〜